# Raise the identity matrix to a power

Tags: matrix, julia

Is it possible to raise the identity matrix to a power? I get an error if I try using the `^` operator.

```
x = [2 0 ; 0 2]
x^2 # this works fine
(2I)^2 #throws MethodError: no method matching ^(::UniformScaling{Int64}, ::Int64)
```

Note: I know that I could simply do `(2^2)I`, but there are cases where this cannot be done (e.g. when a matrix is passed to a function which raises the matrix).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a missing method for `UniformScaling` objects. It would be great if you could open an issue about it so that it can be added in a future release.